# Kafka Lenses SQL - How to WHERE filter based on value of nested object in an array

Tags: sql, apache-kafka

I am trying to filter the record in Kafka Lenses base on the value of an object nested in array. I want to find all records with engineer "id" : "555" in an array.
This are two sample records I want to get where the index of the engineer with "id" : "555" could be different in each record

Record A

```
{
  "payload": {
    "Data": {
      "project": "A"
    },
    "engineer": [
      {
        "name": "Jerry",
        "id": "111",
        "join_date":"12-10-2020"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fanny",
        "id": "555",
        "join_date":"11-23-2020"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Record B

```
{
  "payload": {
    "Data": {
      "project": "B"
    },
    "engineer": [
      {
        "name":"Fanny",
        "id": "555",
        "join_date":"10-18-2021"
      },
      {
        "name":"Terry",
        "id": "999",
        "join_date":"10-26-2020"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obvious, I am not able to do something like ARRAY_CONTAINS
or

```
SELECT * 
FROM topic_name
WHERE payload.engineer[*].id = "555" 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LATERAL JOIN` for the case:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM topic_name LATERAL payload.engineer as engineers
WHERE engineers.id = '555' 
LIMIT 10;
```

The lateral join will explode each payload into two, one for each engineer.

See [Work with arrays](https://help.lenses.io/sql/streaming/explode-arrays/) for more details